# Invalid VHD path error when trying to create Azure Image

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage, azureportal, vhd

I’m trying to create new image using Azure Portal.
When I upload an image as any blob type to container in storage account and try to write a path to it I get the following error: “Invalid VHD blob path. Please make sure the path to the VHD is valid’
The path looks like this: “https://storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/filename”

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please make sure you have a VHD path with `.vhd` format like this: `https://storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/myUploadedVHD.vhd`
Also, it's recommended to upload `.vhd` files to the **page** blob,

[image]

For more references:

- [Prepare a Windows VHD or VHDX to upload to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json)
- [Create a Windows VM from a specialized disk by using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized#option-2-upload-a-specialized-vhd)
- [Creating An Azure VM From The VHDX/VHD File](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-an-azure-vm-from-the-vhdxvhd-file/)

Comment: I uploaded a 128GiB Page Blob to azure but the name didn't end in `.vhd`, and now it's not accepting the path without the extensions despite being a valid path. What can I do? re-uploading the blob again just for renaming is painful..